# Error Handling “Can't find Project or Library” For VBA Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro file in Excel that I developed on my PC with Excel 2016 and should be for someone who works on EXCEL 2010 ans 2013.

On my computer the macro run just fine and did what I needed, but on this someone's computer it showed that error that I never saw as a VBA developer of “Can't find Project or Library” on the first line of the sub I wanted to excute.

Does anyone have any suggestions or suggestions?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/can-t-find-project-or-library. It means a library is referenced from the project that is either not found on the system, or is not checked in the References section of the VBA proejct.

Comment: Use late binding instead of early binding.

Comment: Have you checked for missing references (In VBA-Editor under Tools, References)?

Comment: @FunThomas how can I check those missing refernces

Comment: @braX where I check the binding

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation

Comment: thanks for the link @braX, I was going to ask how to do this as well.

Comment: Missing Reference indeed, as @PaulOgilvie already states. You can check in VBE under `Tools -> References`. 
As @braX says - To avoid this problem, use Late Binding. E.g. `Dim wordApp as Object : Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")` instead of Early Binding: Add a reference to Word Object Libaray vX.X and using `Dim wordApp as Word.Application : Set wordApp = New Word.Application`
Last but not least, make sure the referenced library is installed on the second machine in the first place.

Comment: One thing to add to Paul and Rik's answers.  The missing reference does not even need to be one that is necessary for your script.  If ANY selected reference is not found, it will throw this error whether necessary for your script or not.  As Rik suggested go into the refernces box and uncheck any missing references, then try again.  This is a common problem when a script gets moved from one computer to another when both computers don't have the same excel versions or available references.

Comment: @RikSportel I tried your code and instead of word i wrote excel and it gave me back duplicate declaration

Comment: @braX i added what they said in the link to my code, still the same error.

Comment: By the way, you need to check the missing references on the 2010 machine, not yours.

Comment: it marks all of my variables like lastrow and i and same

Comment: @HarassedDad I understand that, don't konw what to look for. it's a basic sub nothing special

Comment: Did you also remove the Excel reference?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Most likely your project "references" a newer version of Excel itself. Code above is just a sample of using Late Binding. If all your code is native to Excel VBA (you have no additional references), you might just want to copy-paste the workbook without macro's and import all (exported) code modules to fix your issue.

Comment: Ahh yes - your code will have a reference on your machine to excel2016 and office 2016:
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

In the 2010 those references willshow as missing, and should be unticked and the 10.0 references ticked instead.

And these are all in the dialog accessed via Tools, References in the VB Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this pattern:

```
Sub Test()
On Error Goto Finish
Dim obj As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("YourLibName")
...code...
Finish:
End Sub
```

So if you can't create object goto finish.